# BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 works under VS2012, fails on ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, ubuntu

I wrote the following code to detect a person from a video or camera and draw a minimum rectangle around it.

It works well on Windows 7 64-bit with Visual Studio 2012 Express and OpenCV 2.4.9. When I use same code under Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit with Eclipse 3.8 and **OpenCV master branch(whcih is 3.0)**, it said "The type 'BackgroundSubtractorMOG2' must implement the inherited pure virtual methods xxx", where xxx is inherited from 'BackgroundSubtractor'.

From @VictorL [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 & OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866794/backgroundsubtractormog2-opencv), his code for BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 works under ubuntu 12.10 64-bit with OpenCV 2.4.4a.

So I wonder is the implementation for 'BackgroundSubtractorMOG2' different between two versions of OpenCV or the compilers differs from Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04. Anyone has similar problems, and how can I solve it.

Thanks in advance.

```
/*
    1. Detection
        I just use Gaussian Mixture Model(Background Subtraction) here
*/
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int detection();

#define CAMERA 0

#if CAMERA
    VideoCapture cap(-1);
#else
    VideoCapture cap("group.webm");
#endif


int main(){
    if(detection() == -1){
        cout << "Detection failed" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int detection(){
    //check whether the camera is opened
    if(!cap.isOpened()){
        cout << "Camera failed to open" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat originalVideo, currentMat, diffMat, bgMat, binMat, erodeMat, morphMat;
    Mat filledMat;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    namedWindow("currentMat", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    namedWindow("diffMat", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    namedWindow("erodeMat", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    namedWindow("erodeMat2", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    namedWindow("erodeMat3", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    namedWindow("dilate", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    namedWindow("binMat", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    //Gaussian Mixture-based Background/Foreground Segmentation Algorithm.
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 gaussianBgModel;
    gaussianBgModel.set("nmixtures", 3);

    while(1){
        // get a new frame from camera
        cap >> currentMat;
        if(currentMat.empty())
            break;
        imshow("currentMat", currentMat);
        //get the foreground mask
        gaussianBgModel.operator()(currentMat, diffMat);
        imshow("diffMat", diffMat);
        gaussianBgModel.getBackgroundImage(bgMat);
        //do threshold to get binary imahe
        threshold(diffMat, binMat, 252, 255, 0); // Threshold Type 0: Binary
        imshow("binMat", binMat);
        blur(binMat, erodeMat, Size(4, 4));
        imshow("erodeMat", erodeMat);
        threshold(erodeMat, erodeMat, 256/6, 255, 0);
        imshow("erodeMat2", erodeMat);
        int operation = 1 + 2;
        int morph_size = 1;
        Mat element = getStructuringElement(0,
                Size(4 * morph_size + 1, 8 * morph_size + 1),
                Point(morph_size, morph_size));
        Mat elementrect = getStructuringElement(0,
                Size(2 * morph_size + 1, 16 * morph_size + 1),
                Point(morph_size, morph_size));
        dilate(erodeMat, morphMat, element);
        imshow("dilate", morphMat);
        erode(morphMat, morphMat, elementrect);
        imshow("erodeMat3", morphMat);
//--------AFTER ABOVE, PEOPLE IS IDENTIFIED--------------------
//--------NEXT TO FIND COUNTOUR
        // Find contours
        //get a copy of the filtered img
        filledMat = morphMat.clone();

        findContours(filledMat, contours, CV_RETR_TREE,
                CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
        vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
        vector<Point2f> centers(contours.size());
        //      cascadeMat = Mat::zeros(filledMat.size(), 1);
        // Get Bound Rect
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
            approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
            boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[i]));
        }
        /// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects
        Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( filledMat.size(), CV_8UC3 );
        for(unsigned i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ){
            Scalar color = Scalar( 255, 0, 0 );
            //drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
            if(boundRect[i].area() > 3000){
                rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
                Mat roi(currentMat, boundRect[i]);
                namedWindow("ROI", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
                imshow( "ROI", roi );
            }
        }

        /// Show in a window
        namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );
        imshow( "Contours", drawing );


        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you really sure, you're using 2.4.9, not 3.0 ? (the error sounds like, they got some additional get/setters in the new interface). try `cerr << cv::getBuildInformation() << endl;`  if you got the code from github, you might have forgot to `git branch 2.4` and ended up using the master branch

Comment: @berak Sorry, I check my installation source code, it turns out to be the master branch. I try to install 2.4.9 version and run the code again. Thank you for your answer in time, and I will change the question a little.

Comment: no need to be sorry ;)

Comment: @berak Haha, I use OpenCV 2.4.9 and it works perfectly! Thanks again! I will be careful with the newer version of libraries in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to downgrade opencv,  for opencv 3.0 you might want to follow [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html)

main differences are:

```
pMOG2 = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();      //create Background Subtractor objects

pMOG2->apply(frame, fgMaskMOG2);               //update the background model
```

Make sure to link the necessary libraries.