# Error class BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, motion-detection, background-subtraction

I have same the problem like this topic [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 & OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866794/backgroundsubtractormog2-opencv)

Before i use opencv 2.4.9, i have deleted opencv 3.0.0. And now when i use class BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 then i have this prolem.

How can i resolve it. I'm using eclipse. Please, help me.

[image: Error]

My source code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
cv::Mat frame;
cv::Mat back;
cv::Mat fore;
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg;
bg.set("nmixtures", 3);
//bg.bShadowDetection = false;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;

cv::namedWindow("Frame");
cv::namedWindow("Background");

for (;;) {
    cap >> frame;
    bg.operator()(frame, fore);
    bg.getBackgroundImage(back);
    cv::erode(fore, fore, cv::Mat());
    cv::dilate(fore, fore, cv::Mat());
    cv::findContours(fore, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,
            CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    cv::drawContours(frame, contours, -1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    cv::imshow("Frame", frame);
    cv::imshow("Background", back);
    if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0)
        break;
}
return 0;}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
const int nmixtures =3;
const bool bShadowDetection = false;
cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg(nmixtures,bShadowDetection);
```

Change the code like this . It will work .